# Grammatical characterization of deterministic context-free languages

Tags: reference-request, formal-grammars, context-free

Deterministic context-free languages are commonly defined using an *automaton* concept, the (restricted, deterministic) pushdown automaton. To some that is confusing, as the name *context-free* refers to a grammar type.

I seem to remember there exists a characterization of the DCF languages using grammars. In my recollection it used a complicated equivalence on non-terminals. Can anyone provide a pointer to that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia actually [gives you the model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language) and points to [1] for reference: [LR grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_grammar) are equivalent to DPDA.

---

1. [On the Translation of Languages from Left to Right](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958%2865%2990426-2) by Donald Knuth (1965) [[free download](http://cs.nju.edu.cn/dxy/Knuth65.pdf)]

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to re-investigate. The class I was looking for is called *strict deterministic grammars* (Harrison & Havel, JCSS 1973) and characterizes the *prefix-free* deterministic context-free languages. Not all of them. The good side if the class is that is defined on the productions, not on the derivations, like LR-grammars do. Adding an end-marker mekes every language prefix-free, so in practical terms that is not a big loss. Note wikipedia has the notion, hidden under "Strict determinism". (Can I do links in a comment?)

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional note of possible use: the PLL(0) grammars == the strict deterministic grammars, perhaps an easier approach for both understanding and practical application. A nice description is in Parsing Techniques, 2nd Edition, pp354-357.

Comment: Who would the author(s) of the cited book be?

Comment: @vonbrand [Grune/Jacobs](http://books.google.com/books/about/Parsing_Techniques.html?id=05xA_d5dSwAC)  Alas, the previous edition (free online) does not cover this topic and there's no Google Books preview AFAICT.